# SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported

Tags: scp, openssh

Trying to scp files to my server like I've done every day for years... got this weird error today:

```
client$ scp filename.file server:/path/to/somewhere/
SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported
client$ echo $?
255
```

The file does not show up on my server like it would normally after running this command.

This error only appears on scp commands. Using ssh to get into my server works fine.

Has anyone seen this before? How do I go about debugging this? Here's some version info:

```
client$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

```
client$ apt show openssl
Package: openssl
Version: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
```

```
server$ apt show openssh-server
Package: openssh-server
Version: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10
```

```
server$ sshd -V
unknown option -- V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

(note that I've added hostnames "client" and "server" for clarity)

In my sshd_config, it shows `Protocol 2`

```
server$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Protocol
Protocol 2
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my server, which should have maintenance updates through today.

Let me know if I should run any other operations. Server is local network only, but I still want to make sure it's hardened.

Comment: Hey, make sure when you log in via ssh that you use -l letter (for username), rather than 1 (one) arabic symbol, which may cause that error.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ugh, it was a typo... Keeping the post up for others who bang their head against the wall on this as I couldn't find any info on this error message from googling.

It's not in the ssh command (removed various parts for privacy), but I was supplying a port:

`scp -p3122 file server:/path/`

But it really should be:

`scp -P3122 file server:/path/`

(Use a capital 'P')

Comment: This is fixed my problem and is great to know, as I just found out ssh is the opposite and requires lowercase p (ssh -p<port>), or else it will complain about unsupported protocol!

Comment: @abelito yeah, I felt pretty dumb when I posted this, but I knew others would run into the same issue, so I kept this q/a up.

Comment: it's -p for ssh and -P for scp. It's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message with the command 'SSH'.
I fix the problem: that work ONLY if you use 3 elements:  ssh server -l user -p port ..
And the party continue..